# How to avoid to fetch remote response each time in tab

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstreap tabs.
for tabs I am getting response from remote source.
I find for long data content each tab on click each time remote source is called.
I want remote source should be called on first time only.

my link is http://jsfiddle.net/xrcwrn/xhahLd4h/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="tabList"]').click(function (e) {
        var $this = $(this),
            loadurl = $this.attr('href'),
            targ = $this.attr('data-target');
        $.get(loadurl, function (data) {
            $(targ).html(data);
        });
        $this.tab('show');
        return false;
    });
})
```

How to achive this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add some data to the target once it is loaded the first time, and test it :

**[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/e5j7cLp4/)**

```
if (!$(targ).data('loaded')) {
    console.log('The data was not already loaded');
    $.get(loadurl, function (data) {
        // here you "flag" the target to a "loaded" state
        $(targ).html(data).data('loaded', true); 
    });
} else {
    console.log('The data was already loaded');
}
```

**Note :** you may want to trigger a click to the first tab after page load with

```
$('[data-toggle="tabList"]:first').click();
```

**Or** to disable ajax loading on first tab, use this test instead :

```
if (!$(targ).data('loaded') && $this.parent('li').index() !== 0)
```

or if you can, simply add the attribute `data-loaded` to the first target :

```
<div class="tab-pane active" id="a" data-loaded="1">
```

Comment: 1 more thing. how to disable ajax data load only for tab 1. Other should work as above.